# custom error message with more html validate

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Hello I want to create a custom error alert in HTML
here I want to custom in( required) and another for ( max and min number)

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="durationdays">Days</label><br>
<input type="number" name="duration" max="5" min="1" class="form-control" style="width:50%" required oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);"     oninput="InvalidMsg(this);">
</div>
```

and this is a javascript code

```
function InvalidMsg(textbox) {

           if (textbox.value === '') {
               textbox.setCustomValidity
                     ('Required');
           } else if (textbox.validity.typeMismatch) {
               textbox.setCustomValidity
                     ('ONlY number');
           } else {
               textbox.setCustomValidity('');
           }

           return true;
       }
```

I want if the user clicks on send button with empty value show this(Required)
and if enter letter value show (ONLY number)
and if enter less than 1 or more than 5 show (should be less than or equal 5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `` textbox.setCustomValidity(`Max: ${textbox.max} Min:${textbox.min}`); `` to get the min and max values, then it's possible to show the numbers. The other ones should work fine.